# FileReader path error - File Not Found

Tags: android, relative-path

I have included my `root-CA.crt` file in `app/src/main/assets`.

---

I have typed this and ran on the emulator.

```
PEMParser reader = new PEMParser(new FileReader("file:///android_asset/root-CA.crt"));

            X509CertificateHolder caCertHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) reader.readObject();
            reader.close();
```

---

And got this error:

```
10-18 20:47:34.601 10617-10617/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/root-CA.crt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-18 20:47:34.601 10617-10617/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
10-18 20:47:34.601 10617-10617/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
10-18 20:47:34.601 10617-10617/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
10-18 20:47:34.611 10617-10617/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
```

Why I am getting this error ?? I have already mentioned the correct path. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:///android_asset` is only meaningful with `WebView`. It cannot be used elsewhere.

Use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on the content represented by your asset. Wrap that in an `InputStreamReader` as needed.

Comment: Thanks...!! What will be the end result for the above `new FileReader("file:///android_asset/root-CA.crt")` code or the whole code? I am really new to android development.

Comment: @Senura: I cannot tell you that. You get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on a `Context` (e.g., an `Activity`), and I do not know where this code resides. In [this sample activity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.7/Camera/EXIFRotater/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/exif/MainActivity.java), I use `open()` to get an `InputStream` on an image, packaged as an asset, that I pass along to an `ExifInterface` object.

Comment: Thank you... I've done what you've told... and now it works. Appreciate sharing your knowledge. +1